# Do I get ALL solutions for the heat equation by using the separation of variables?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

Let's assume the heat equation as:
$$\frac{\partial \omega_1}{\partial t}=\nu(\frac{\partial^2 \omega_1}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \omega_1}{\partial x_2^2})$$
Using the separation of variables as $\omega_1=X_1(x_1)X_2(x_2)T(t)$ one can find a solution as:
$$\omega_1=(C_1 \cos(\sqrt{a}x_1)+C_2 \sin(\sqrt{a}x_1))(C_3 \cos(\sqrt{b}x_2)+C_4 \sin(\sqrt{b}x_2))e^{-\nu(a+b)t}$$
Let's now assume a second function $\omega_2$ which also needs to solve the heat equation, thus can be written as:
$$\omega_2 = (K_1 \cos(\sqrt{a}x_1)+ K_2 \sin(\sqrt{a}x_1))(K_3 \cos(\sqrt{b}x_2)+ K_4 \sin(\sqrt{b}x_2))e^{-\nu(a+b)t}$$
Both functions need to fulfill the boundary conditions $\omega_i(x_2=0)=0$ and $\omega_i(x_2=L)=0$ and the continuity equation $\frac{\partial \omega_1}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial \omega_2}{\partial x_2}=0$.
How can I assure that by using the separation of variables I get ALL the solutions needed to solve this set of conditions?

Comment: There seem to be some boundary conditions - please state these as well.

Comment: As I remember it, separation of variables finds the solution for simple distributions of values on the boundary.  Then you call on the linearity of the equation to say that for a complex distribution of values you can expand it as a sum of the simple distributions you have solutions for.  What is needed is a theorem that says any reasonable distribution of variables on the boundary can be expanded this way.  We have one for Fourier analysis that says any function that is continuous except for a finite number of discontinuities can be expanded.

Comment: I remember asking this question in class many years ago.  I was told you need a completeness theorem for the boundary functions you solve for.  It was a physics class, not a math class, and no such theorem was provided.  In another context it was said you need to be able to expand a delta function of boundary values, which makes sense to me as a way to prove completeness.

Answer (score 1):

There are some uniqueness theorems that tell you that certain initial-boundary value problems for the heat equation cannot have more than one solution. The goal of separation of variables is only to find **a** solution to the problem. Once you have found a solution, then you invoke a uniqueness theorem to show that it is the **only** solution.